# Why the document cannot print acronyms and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have saved glossaries and acronyms in `Glossay.tex` file and I include in the latex main thesis document using `\input{Appendices/Glossary.tex}`. I have followed the template in overleaf, however, the document does not show the acronym list and glossaries

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % for Glossary and definitions
\makeglossaries

\input{Appendices/Glossary.tex}

\begin{document}
.....
....
...
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
%\input{Appendices/Glossary}
\printglossary

% Now begin the Appendices, including them as separate files

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

%\input{Appendices/AppendixA}   % Appendix Title
%\input{Appendices/Glossary.tex}
%\input{Appendices/AppendixB} % Appendix Title


\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\backmatter
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  % Change the left side page header to "Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{mybib}  % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"


\end{document}
```

what could be the reason?

The entries in the `Glossary.tex` the file looks like this:

```
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\newacronym{crf}{CRFs}{conditional random fields}
```

Comment: In your current MWE you are not using any of the acronyms with `\gls` or similar commands, is that the issue you are seeing? Maybe you make a complete MWE that actually shows the complete commands in one file?

Comment: @TobiBS I do not have any glossary entry, it is all acronyms. That is why there is no `\gls` command. If you have a look on acronyms in this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/glossaries) it has similar pattern as mine. but I am not sure why it is not showing the list of acronyms...

Comment: It doesn‘t matter if you define acronyms or glossary entries, `\gls` can be used for both of them. But this is why I wrote or similar: If you use `\acs` that‘s fine, too. But if you don‘t acces any of the acronyms, it will never show up in the list of acronyms.